# Can I make multiple assignments within a given case_when true clause?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Update: Apparently this feature is now planned for dplyr, as discussed here: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/6145

In SQL one can assign multiple variables - say var1 and var2 - when a given case is verified, with a construction like

case when condition then var1 = x, var2 = y

Does dplyr::case_when (or anything else in the tidyverse) support this useful feature), and if so, how?!

Note that in the example below, var1, var2  and var3 have exactly the same test conditions, i.e. Species == "setosa", and the degenerate case TRUE. I want to reduce this redundancy by not repeating the conditions: *one* call to case_when (or similar), albeit with different eval_on_true expressions for var1, var2 and var3, respectively. Obviously redundancy is not a problem here in this example, but my case_when's get very large and complex in real life examples.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create example data
set.seed(1337)
data <- iris %>%
  sample_n(5) %>%
  select(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species) %>%
  as_tibble()
data
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#>          <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#> 1          5.5         1.8 virginica 
#> 2          5           1.9 virginica 
#> 3          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#> 4          5.9         2.3 virginica 
#> 5          4.1         1.3 versicolor
data %>%
  mutate(var1 = case_when(Species == "setosa" ~ "green", TRUE ~ "blue"),
         var2 = case_when(Species == "setosa" ~ Petal.Length * 99, TRUE ~ Petal.Length),
         var3 = case_when(Species == "setosa" ~ as.Date("2002-12-01"), TRUE ~ as.Date("2003-12-02")))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    var1   var2 var3      
#>          <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>      <chr> <dbl> <date>    
#> 1          5.5         1.8 virginica  blue    5.5 2003-12-02
#> 2          5           1.9 virginica  blue    5   2003-12-02
#> 3          1.5         0.2 setosa     green 148.  2002-12-01
#> 4          5.9         2.3 virginica  blue    5.9 2003-12-02
#> 5          4.1         1.3 versicolor blue    4.1 2003-12-02
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @akrun Thanks. I have now done this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `case_when` is that accepts a value whose `length` is either `nrow` or 1. Therefore, you have to trick `case_when` by producing a list of `nrow` 1-row dataframes.
The accessor function `lod` (defined below) constructs a list of 1-row dataframes:

```r
lod <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  do.call(function(...) mapply(data.frame, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE), args)
}

lod(x = 1:4, y = letters[1:4])

[[1]]
  x y
1 1 a

[[2]]
  x y
1 2 b

[[3]]
  x y
1 3 c

[[4]]
  x y
1 4 d
```

Then write your `case_when` statement, using `lod` to group variables, as follows:

```r
data |>
  mutate(case_when(Species == "setosa" ~
                     lod(var1 = "green",
                         var2 = Petal.Length * 99,
                         var3 = as.Date("2002-12-01")),
                   TRUE ~
                     lod(var1 = "blue",
                         var2 = Petal.Length,
                         var3 = as.Date("2003-12-02"))) |>
         bind_rows())

+ # A tibble: 5 x 6
  Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    var1   var2 var3      
         <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>      <chr> <dbl> <date>    
1          5.5         1.8 virginica  blue    5.5 2003-12-02
2          5           1.9 virginica  blue    5   2003-12-02
3          1.5         0.2 setosa     green 148.  2002-12-01
4          5.9         2.3 virginica  blue    5.9 2003-12-02
5          4.1         1.3 versicolor blue    4.1 2003-12-02
```

The final `bind_rows` is required for `mutate` to accept the new variables.

Comment: Thanks! I like this a lot! I'll postpone accepting this for a little though in case anyone else wants to chip in.

Comment: Perhaps combined with the definition: case_when_n = function(...) bind_rows(case_when(...)) to avoid repeating that.

Comment: @JRC tbh, the idea of multiple assignments in `case_when` statements is quite sensible and probably deserves an official feature request.

Comment: hmmm. interesting. how would one do that?

Comment: @JRC I would look into [issues](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues)

Answer (score 1):

If we want to create new columns by multiplying a single column with different values, one `tidyverse` approach is to use `imap` (by default the default `.y` is the sequence if we pass unnamed elements) to loop over the multiplier values, return a single column with `transmute` and then bind those columns with the original data

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
imap_dfc(c(10, 99), ~ data %>% 
   transmute(!! str_c('var', .y) := 
   case_when(Species == "setosa"~ Petal.Length * .x, 
              TRUE ~ Petal.Length))) %>% 
   bind_cols(data, .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 7
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species     var1  var2
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
1          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8 virginica    5.5   5.5
2          6.3         2.5          5           1.9 virginica    5     5  
3          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa      15   148. 
4          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3 virginica    5.9   5.9
5          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor   4.1   4.1
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. This is ingenious, but doesn't quite get the desired generality. I have changed the reprex to make the desired level of generality a little more clear . Apologies if it was not too clear at first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create example data
set.seed(1337)
data <- iris %>%
  sample_n(5) %>%
  as_tibble()
data
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#> 1          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8 virginica 
#> 2          6.3         2.5          5           1.9 virginica 
#> 3          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#> 4          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3 virginica 
#> 5          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor

data %>%
  mutate(
    sepal_size = case_when(
      Sepal.Length > 6 & Sepal.Width > 3 ~ "big",
      Sepal.Width > 3 ~ "medium",
      TRUE ~ "small"
    ),
    petal_size = case_when(
      Petal.Length > 5 ~ "big",
      TRUE ~ "small"
    ),
    is_fancy = TRUE
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 8
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    sepal_size
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>      <chr>     
#> 1          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8 virginica  big       
#> 2          6.3         2.5          5           1.9 virginica  small     
#> 3          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa     medium    
#> 4          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3 virginica  big       
#> 5          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor small     
#> # … with 2 more variables: petal_size <chr>, is_fancy <lgl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>
To do the reverse, you can do:

```
iris %>%
  mutate(
    selected = Species == "setosa",
    var1 = ifelse(selected, Petal.Length * 99, Petal.Length),
    var2 = ifelse(selected, as.Date("2002-12-01"), as.Date("2003-12-02"))
  )
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. I was however hoping to do all this within one call to case_when. This would be ideal because I want both my new variables to be derived *for the same case/conditions*.

Comment: Then you can use `mutate(across())` syntax to apply a `case_when` on multiple columns

Comment: Many thanks for the help, although I don't quite see it yet.

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html#ref-examples

Comment: `iris %>% mutate(across(starts_with("Sepal"), ~ case_when(.x > 5 ~ "big", .x > 3 ~ "medium", TRUE ~ "small")))`

Comment: Very interesting. However, this answers the converse question, i.e. how to vary the *test conditions* but keep the same expressions to evaluate when the tests are verified. My question is: when a given test condition is TRUE, how can i evaluate multiple expressions and introduce multiple corresponding new variables var1, var2...

Comment: @JRC I revised my answer